# C++ a class to be used only by another class

Tags: c++, class, nested-class

I'm building a class (class A) which needs to be able to create a number of instances of another class (class B) in the course of its operation, but class B is only used by a few member functions of class A, and never used outside of the class. How should class B best be defined? Is it practical / reasonable to make it a private member of Class A? Is this the intended purpose of nested classes, or am I parting with the spirit of the construct?

Thanks,
Wyatt

EDIT: On further consideration, I'm not really asking about best practice, as this is for a personal project. I want to include class B as a member of class A from an encapsulation standpoint - it just seems reasonable that a class which is wholly subordinate should in fact be a part of its owning class.

What I'm wondering is whether or not this is a reasonable use-case for nested classes? If not, what is the purpose of nested classes?

Answer (score 3):

*One* possibility is to define a namespace called `detail` inside the namespace where you put your classes. e.g.

```
// public_namespace_detail.hpp
namespace public_namespace
{
    namespace detail
    {
        class B
        {
          ...
        };

    }
}

// public_namespace.hpp
#include "public_namespace_detail.hpp"

namespace public_namespace
{
    class A
    {
       detail::B b;
       ...       
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just make `class B` completely unrelated to `class A` -- if nothing else, it's going to make it easier to write tests if you can test `class A` and `class B` separately. If you don't want to go that route, prevent anyone from instantiating `class B` except `class A` by defining `class B`, making it have a private constructor, and then making `class A` a `friend`.

Comment: From a coding standpoint I'm not even worried about others instantiating it, this is all for a private project, it's just a matter of encapsulation. It feels wrong to declare a class innately related to another as an entirely separate object. My question isn't so much about best practice as it is about whether or not this is a reasonable use of a nested class. I realise that's not what I asked, and I'll edit my question.

Comment: @wyatt: IMHO, there are no reasonable uses of nested classes in C++.

Comment: @Billy ONeal What were they initially for, if they're no longer a viable structure?

Comment: @Wyatt: Since when does C++ prevent you from doing things that aren't viable? My guess is that they were added because Java has them.

Comment: @Billy: C++ nested classes have very little in common with Java inner classes (Java doesn't have nested classes per se, although a static inner class comes pretty close)

Comment: @Ben: Then I don't see why they exist.

Comment: @Billy: They aren't necessary, but none of C++'s features are (after all, C or assembly are also Turing-complete).  They happen to be rather nice for the pimpl idiom, to make the implementation class literally an internal detail inaccessible to the rest of the world.

Comment: @Ben: My point is, I think they lead to unmaintainable mess. Just an opinion thing.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options :

1. private inheritance : **`class A : private B {};`**
2. nested class : **`class A { class B { /* etc */ }; };`**
3. Good ol' private member to class **B** from class **A** : **`class A { B b; };`**

I personally would go with the nested class if you're 100% sure it's not needed outside.

Comment: private inheritance isn't really a proper option at all.  He is not trying to model a "was-a" relationship.

Comment: @Brent: `private` inheritance is `implemented-in-terms-of`, not `was-a`.

Comment: Just to be sure, if class B were nested within class A, it would behave exactly as a class declared globally would, provided it were referenced from within class A? I can't seem to find many good references discussing nested classes.

Comment: private inheritance and private member are likely not suitable options, not because of any *is-a* relationship, but because they enforce that each instance of `A` is associated with exactly one instance of `B`.

Comment: @wyatt correct, also AraK's namespace solution is good, completely forgot about that.

Comment: @wyatt, @OneOfOne: No, a nested class does not behave the same as another class at namespace scope.  Nested classes are members of the enclosing class and therefore can access private and protected members.

Answer (score 0):

A general rule of thumb for me is that if I find I have a difficult problem with inheritance then I've probably looked at the problem in the wrong way.

Is there a way you can restructure your program so the classes are less "coupled"?
I.E. Can you move the functions out of class A that reference class B (and place them in B)?

Comment: His problem does not pertain to inheritance.

Comment: The two classes can easily be separated, but one is only useful with regard to the other. The relationship between the two classes is rather similar to that of a string and a regex class - class A being the string, and class B being a compiled regex statement. I could implement them separately, but since class B is only useful for class A, and class A is a rather specific class in itself, it seems a touch silly.

Comment: As a note, I'm not trying to obfuscate the purpose of the classes, it's just a bit convoluted and not terribly important.

Answer (score 0):

I would move it outside of B, since otherwise it will be exposed to other classes via the header file of A (whether you like it or not).  Said differently, if you change the implementation of B, then clients of A must recompile - since B was declared inside of A.

The structure of my project should make it clear that the header file for B, should not be used by other classes.  For example, I have a folder called "exports" where I place all my header files that I intend to be shared outside the project.  Obviously B's header won't be found there.

In a different language that does not use header files, such as C#, I will casually place B inside of A, if B is fairly small - perhaps not more than 6-10 lines of declaration.

Comment: Defining `B` inside `A` is a separate question from making `B` a nested class of (and therefore having access to private members of) `A`.  C++ isn't Java or C#.

Comment: @Ben: I am only addressing nested classes (which is the topic of the question).  And actually, nested classes do not have access to private members of the enclosing class.  See here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr061.htm

Comment: Almost everything you said in your answer is based on the definition of `B` being inside the header file for `A`... but that isn't required for a nested class.

Comment: Furthermore, quoting documentation from some obscure compiler doesn't help.  According to the C++0x draft, <quote> A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member.</quote>.  If this behavior is new to C++0x, I'd appreciate the quote from the earlier standard (not IBM compiler) you're using.

Comment: nested classes **do** have access to private members of the enclosing class.  See the new code example in my answer.  The IBM behavior you referred to is not standard-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a nested class is fine here.

Note that to keep the code organized, I wouldn't place the definition of `B` inside `A`.  Instead:

```
class A
{
    class B;
};

class A::B
{
};
```

Among other things, this allows the definition of class `A::B` to be placed inside A's implementation file.

EDIT: Since there seems to be some confusion about whether a nested class gets access to the containing class's private members, I provide a code snippet to prove that it does:

```
class A
{
    int x;

    class B
    {
        int func(A* p) { return p->x; }
    };
};
```

- GCC 4.3.4: [Accepted.](http://ideone.com/Y3dVv)

[Variant without inline definition of `A::B`, also accepted:](http://ideone.com/XCSUr)

```
class A
{
    int x;

    class B;
};

class A::B
{
    int func(A* p) { return p->x; }
};
```

- Comeau: Accepted (both variants)

> Your Comeau C/C++ test results are as
>   follows:
>
> Comeau C/C++ 4.3.10.1 (Oct  6 2008
>   11:28:09) for ONLINE_EVALUATION_BETA2
>   Copyright 1988-2008 Comeau Computing. 
>   All rights reserved. MODE:strict
>   errors C++ noC++0x_extensions
>
> In strict mode, with -tused, Compile
>   succeeded (but remember, the Comeau
>   online compiler does not link). 
>   Compiled with C++0x extensions
>   DISabled.